# Get emails of register user in Wordpress

Tags: email, user-registration

I have a client who want to make a register form to enter in the web, and then get all the emails to use them in email marketing.

Is there a plugin o SQL query that can get all this information easly?
Thanks (and sorry about my english),
Carlos

Comment: If your client is going to want to be sending out emails, they need to be *very* careful because it's easy to get marked as a spammer.  I would **strongly** suggest you use a service like mailchimp, aweber, etc.  All the major services will have sign up forms for you plug right in.

Comment: Yes im aware of that. But the thing here is that i dont know how to get all the emails of register people in one piece. Probably making i SQL query i can get it, but i was wondering if isnt a plugin or something that my client can use.

Comment: Plugins recommendations are [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.  If you give a shot yourself and get stuck during the implementation I'm sure people here would be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

The user table column you are searching for is `user_email`

```
$emails = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'fields'  => array( 'display_name', 'user_email', ), // you don't want everything, right?
    'orderby' => 'email',                                // 'user_email' works as well
    'order'   => 'ASC',                                  // default: 'DESC'
    'number'  => 10,                                     // total amount of users to return
    'offset'  => 0,                                      // use in combination with 'number' to page results
    'search'  => '*@*',
    'search_columns' => 'user_email',
    'blog_id' => get_current_blog_id(),                  // Multisite needs that, allows cross site search
    'role'    => 'subscriber',                           // in case you want to exclude admins, etc.
    'exclude' => array( 1, ),                            // Blacklist user IDs
) );
```

Then there's the filter `pre_user_query` that you can use to get the whole class back. You can also use it to debug your query:

```
<?php /* Plugin Name: Debug User Query */
add_filter( 'pre_user_query', function( &$query )
{
    var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_query']->last_query );
    return $query;
} );
```